# Laravel - Race condition and make a new booking when status_booking is EXPIRED

Tags: php, laravel, race-condition

i want to ask you all.
I need to handle race condition (already make it) i use chace::lock and i need to add new code (so if passenger cancelled the booking, new passenger can make a new booking (so, it will available again)
for booking car

here is on my Contoller (on laravel)

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $lockKey = 'charter-lock-' . $id;
    
    if (!Cache::lock($lockKey)->get()) {
        session()->flash('alert', [
            'title' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Sorry, not available.',
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
            
            $nameb = $request->input('nameb');
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $mobileb = $request->input('mobileb');
            $status = $request->input('status', 'ONLINE');
            
            $charter = Charter::find($id);
            $total_amount = $charter->tarif;
            
            $bookingCar = BookingCar::FirstOrCreate([
                'user_id' => auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
                'charter_id' => $id,
                'nameb' => $nameb,
                'email' => $email,
                'mobileb' => $mobileb,
                'status' => $status,
                'total_amount' => $total_amount,
            ]);
            
            $booking_car_id = BookingCar::orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get();
            foreach ($booking_car_id as $b) {
                $b_id = $b->id;
            }
                $id = $request['id'];
                $names = $request['name'];
                $mobile = $request['mobile'];
                $address = $request['address'];
                $destination = $request['destination'];
                            
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
                $charterticket = CharterTicket::create([
                    'id' => Str::random(6),
                    'booking_car_id' => $b_id,
                    'name' => $names[$i],
                    'mobile' => $mobile[$i],
                    'address' => $address[$i],
                    'destination' => $destination[$i],
            ]);
            
            }
            
            $bookingCar = BookingCar::where('id', $b_id)->first();
            //another code for payment
            $payment = Payment::create([
                'booking_car_id' => $b_id,

            ]);
            DB::commit();

            Cache::lock($lockKey)->release();
        
            return redirect()->route('payments.bookingcar.create', ['bookingcar' => $bookingCar->id]);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        session()->flash('alert', [
            'title' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'An error occurred while processing the booking.',
        ]);
        DB::rollBack();
        Cache::lock($lockKey)->release();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

i need to know where should i put $bookingCar->status_booking == 'EXPIRED' so other passenger can make a new booking, becasue im trying to add that, but still display " 'Sorry, not available.'".
thanks a lot

Comment: your `total` insn't add/sub by booking? like, if expired,canceled,deleted etc you add, if you book then sub the total..

Comment: no, probably it should total_amount = $charter->tarif. so i did not need add/sub (i'm not change it, probably i should) cause it will booking for one car only.

Comment: why `$harga = Charter::where('id', $id)->get();` , use the `::find($id)`, and you don't need the for each on `$h->tarif`, this is 1 row btw.

Comment: thank you for correct the code. i will edit it